# spring security 3.0 restfull authentification for mobile client

Tags: spring, security, rest, authentication, mobile

We have an existing jsf/spring application that uses spring security for authentication and authorization.

Now we want to add a restful web service layer, to be used by a mobile client (native android app.)  The existing authentication process uses `j_spring_security_check` and a custom filter.

Can I handle the restful api authentication and authorization within the same context? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create another security configuration for the API realm. Configure it to HTTP BASIC authentication (if that suits you and if API is served over https).

For example:

```
<http use-expressions="true" pattern="/api/**" realm="API Realm" create-session="stateless">    
     ...
     <http-basic />
     ...
     <logout logout-url="/api/logout" />
</http>
```

EDIT:
As per commenter's comment, I'm correcting my answer: this method unfortunately won't work in Spring Security 3.0 because multiple http elements in Spring Security config were added in 3.1.

Comment: i don't think that spring security **3.0** allow multiple http tags

Comment: For 3.0, perhaps it's possible to define DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint in spring security configuration that delegates to LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint for web app's URLs and BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint for API URLs.

Comment: sounds logical, i'll try it. but for now i'm using annotations to secure my api and it works ! (of course with api path filter set to "none")